# Viewbinding generated files generating for AndroidTest

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

Been noticing that android viewbinding files are sometimes being generated for `AndroidTest`. Did something change in the newest AndroidStudio? Is this a bug that just popped up?

This causes problems since you'll get something like "...R cannot be found" under AndroidTest generated databinding/viewbinding folder (since AndroidTest won't have that).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not a bug, it should be that you inadvertently enabled databinding.
After this function is enabled, the AndroidTest file similar to the Activity file is automatically generated in the Text file. You can take a look at the two-way data binding feature, which was developed by Google in the last two years and works well with the MVVM framework.

Comment: The generated text file can be directly deleted. If you do not use it, delete it and build the project.